# can't verify selected checkbox, Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my test I want to verify selected checkbox. Below is my code

```
if (CheckboxForFirstCitizenship.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("Checkbox selected");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Checkbox not selected");
    }
    if (CheckboxForSecondCitizenship.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("Checkbox selected");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Checkbox not selected");
    }
```

Web elements I have in PageObjects class

```
@FindBy(xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/ufe-root[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ng-component[1]/div[1]/ufe-klient[1]/app-dashboard[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/app-individual-client-edit-container[1]/app-process-container[1]/app-local-loader[1]/div[1]/div[3]/app-individual-client-edit-client-data[1]/app-form-container[1]/p-accordion[1]/div[1]/p-accordiontab[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/app-form-data-set-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-individual-client-edit-personal-data-form[1]/app-data-container[1]/div[1]/div[2]/app-container-state[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/app-individual-client-edit-citizenship-form[1]/div[2]/p-checkbox[1]/div[1]/div[2]")
@CacheLookup
public WebElement CheckboxForFirstCitizenship;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/ufe-root[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ng-component[1]/div[1]/ufe-klient[1]/app-dashboard[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/app-individual-client-edit-container[1]/app-process-container[1]/app-local-loader[1]/div[1]/div[3]/app-individual-client-edit-client-data[1]/app-form-container[1]/p-accordion[1]/div[1]/p-accordiontab[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/app-form-data-set-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-individual-client-edit-personal-data-form[1]/app-data-container[1]/div[1]/div[2]/app-container-state[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/app-individual-client-edit-citizenship-form[1]/div[2]/p-checkbox[1]/label[1]")
@CacheLookup
public WebElement CheckboxForSecondCitizenship;
```

[image]

In test result I have two printlines 'Checkbox not selected' despite of firstCheckox is selected. What I'm doing wrong? Can someone help?

```
<p-checkbox _ngcontent-c26="" binary="true" class="control__hint ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" label="Główne" id="main-citizenship-checkbox-0" style="" xpath="1">
    <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input type="checkbox" name="undefined" value="undefined">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable pi pi-check"></span></div>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <label class="ui-chkbox-label ui-label-active ng-star-inserted">Główne</label>
</p-checkbox>
```

Comment: Share HTML of the checkboxes in text format

Comment: <p-checkbox _ngcontent-c26="" binary="true" class="control__hint ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" label="Główne" id="main-citizenship-checkbox-0" style="" xpath="1"><div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input type="checkbox" name="undefined" value="undefined"></div><div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable pi pi-check"></span></div></div><!----><label class="ui-chkbox-label ui-label-active ng-star-inserted">Główne</label></p-checkbox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `isSelected` method, you have to address to the `input type="checkbox"` element.
 
Use css selector `#main-citizenship-checkbox-0 input` for the first checkbox.
Probably for the second one, it will be `#main-citizenship-checkbox-1 input`.

```
@FindBy(css = "#main-citizenship-checkbox-0 input")
@CacheLookup
public WebElement checkboxForFirstCitizenship;
```

Comment: I change from xpath to css and it's correct. Thanks for help.